# How to align an object to remain flat along a spiral?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I´m trying to shape a seaweed along a spiral but I cannot get it to work properly. I´ve seen I have to mess with geometry nodes but the problem is that this would be the firs time I need to do so and I keep getting confused.

I´ve tried to watch video and read explanations but I keep messing up.

[image]

As you can see the axis are all over when I just wanted the kelp to remain flat all the way down. I´m self-taught and do this mainly for fun but things like this really frustrate me to no end.

Here is my file [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your curve and in *Edit* mode choose *Twist Method > Z-U*p and in the *N panel > Item > Mean Tilt*, choose 90°:

[image]